# How to show data from multiple tables in a report using report viewer?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm using report viewer in windows form application to show the data  of a student from multiple tables. I've checked the query using query builder to show the data and it works. But when I'm using the same query while binding with the report.rdlc and report viewer it gives me the error while generating the report. Here in the following is my query and error that I'm facing.
**Query:**

```
SELECT
    tblStudent.stdRNo, tblStudent.stdName, tblStudent.stdFName, tblInstallments.DueOn,
    tblInstallments.submitted, tblInstallments.feeParInst,
    tblClasses.className,
    tblClasses.departName, tblInstallments.InstId 
FROM
  (((tblStudent INNER JOIN
     tblInstallments ON tblStudent.stdRNo = tblInstallments.stdId
    ) INNER JOIN
     tblFee ON tblStudent.stdRNo = tblFee.stdID AND tblInstallments.stdId = tblFee.stdID
   ) INNER JOIN
     tblClasses ON tblStudent.stdRNo = tblClasses.stdId
  )
WHERE (tblStudent.stdRNo = ?)
  AND (tblClasses.departName = ?)
  AND (tblClasses.className = ?)
```

**Error:**
[image]
Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong, which is obvious?

Answer (score 0):

tblStudent.stdRNo in query is looks like int but you are passing string. Format **txtrno.text** in int and try.